# Finding the minimum number of machines working

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A system comprising of **n** identical components works with probability 0.8, if at least one of all other components works. Each of the components works with probability 0.8, independent of all other components. The minimum value of n for which the system works with probability at least 0.97 is

my soln: 
prob that system will work $\ge 0.97$
=Pr(at least one component is working)[as system will work if at least one component is working]$\ge 0.97$

=$1-\text{Pr(none of the component is working)}\ge0.97\\= 1-(0.2)^n\ge0.97\\=-(0.2)^n\ge -0.03\\(0.2)^n\le 0.03\\nlog(0.2)\le log(0.03)\\=n\ge \frac{log(.03)}{log(0.2)}\\n\ge 2.17(approx)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result should be $n \ge 2.17,$ so you need $n=3$. For $n=2$ the chance of failure is $0.2^2=0.04,$ too high

Comment: how can I get $n\ge2.17$ i edit the steps where am I wrong? thanks for help

Comment: oh yeah log(0.2) is a negative value thanks